# Origin of Laue equations?

Tags: history, crystals, lattice-model, braggs-law

The [Bragg condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bragg%27s_law) (by Bragg in 1913) can be derived by the [Laue equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laue_equations) that is making use of the [Miller indices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_index) and all the latice/crystal stuff (so basically it's bringing Bragg's law to more fundamental ground).

But what is interesting to me: When did the "Laue way" came up? Was it only named after Max von Laue or did he himself publish a paper introducing this formalism?

Neither Wikipedia nor the books I have are citing it. The Laue diffraction/condition/law is always just presented without origin. But I'd like to find it's real origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When did the "Laue way" came up? Was it only named after Max von Laue or did he himself publish a paper introducing this formalism?

Max von Laue submitted his equations for publication 08 June 1912.  The paper is [W. Friedrich, P. Knipping and M. Laue, "Interferenzerscheinungen bei Röntgenstrahlen
", Annalen der Physik, volume 346, issue 10, pages 971-988, 1913](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/andp.19133461004/abstract)
.  It is also cited as Sitzungberichte. Bayerische Akademie der Wissenschaften, pp. 303-322 (1912).  There is also a 1981 English translation by J. Stezowski as "Interference phenomona for X-rays" in Benchmark Papers in Physical Chemistry and Chemical Physics.

Laue's equations came first; then Bragg developed the simplified condition.

See Early Days of X-ray Crystallography, by Andre Authier for more infomation.