# Bragg reflected electrons

Tags: electrons, reflection

Could you explain how does bragg reflection happen for electrons? What does it mean that when they satisfy [Laue condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laue_equations)? This already is [asked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48162/origin-of-laue-equations) in Physics SE. They are Bragg reflected in the opposite direction?

I don't understand, if they satisfy Laue or [Bragg condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bragg%27s_law), they should interfere constructively, but why should they be reflected "to the left" if they were moving "to the right"?

Comment: Why do you think they're reflected to the left if they're moving to the right?

Comment: Apologies. I dont know what was wrong with my grammar that day.It is well known that you lose suffix s if you ask a question like "How DOES etc..."

Comment: Why do I think that? It is not me who thinks that...The book I read says so. And, of course, when you think about conduction, when electrons, while accelerating, reach 1st Brillouin zone boundary, they appear on the other side, if you look at it in the reduced zone scheme, and they start moving from the beginning of the zone. And no, this question has not been asked or, at least, link that is given here does not lead to it. Never mind, i found out that this place is not so good for seeking answers anyway.